# which statistical analysis to use?

Tags: statistical-significance

Please allow me to explain the background for my questions first. I ran a specific test comprising of adding various doses of a certain chemical and then measuring the effect of these various doses on the cleanliness of a liquid product. I repeated the same test about 30 times, with the same doses each time (i.e., for each time I ran the test), and I would every time measure the same parameter related to the cleanliness of my product. Knowing that the relationship is non-linear, how can I see if there is a correlation between my dose and my cleanliness parameter? And if there is a correlation (strong, week, or non-existent), how do I find out from this correlation what would be the best dose to use in the future? Let me give you an example of what I am doing:

Let's say I have 5 jars. I add 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 spoons of chemical to different jars. I add 10 to the first, 20 to the second, etc. Each jar contains the same volume of my liquid product to start with. These 5 doses (the 10, 20, 30, 40, 50) would be my first variable. After I am done my reaction time, I measure how clean the liquid product is (let's say how many sand particles there are). That measurement is my second variable (or the result of he experiment). Knowing that by adding more chemical does not mean cleaner product (it is a non-linear relationship), how can I see what the correlation is (if there is one), and how can I predict which dose of chemical will give me the cleaner liquid product? Remember that I also repeated the same experiment 30 or so times to see if the results are repeatable.

Comment: First I would graph the data, with a scatter plot of chemical concentration vs cleanlinesss.  It could be that no further analysis is even necessary.

Comment: Can you try to change to a more informative title?